# List not declared in scope

Tags: c++, list, class, declare

So I'm trying to call on my `list` of `Edge*`s called `edgelist`. I have a `graph.cpp` below that is supposed to display an adjacency list of the graph.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "Graph.hpp"

Graph::Graph(){}

void Graph::displayGraph(){
for(int i = 0; i < vertices[vertices.size()-1].label; i++){
    cout << vertices[i].label << ": ";
    for(int j = 0; j <= edgeList.size(); j++){
        if(edgeList[j].start==i){
            cout << edgeList[j].end;
        }
    }
}
}
```

`Graph.hpp` includes `Vertex.hpp` which is below.

```
#ifndef Vertex_hpp
#define Vertex_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "Edge.hpp"
using namespace std;

class Vertex {
public:
// the label of this vertex
int label;
// using a linked-list to manage its edges which offers O(c) insertion
list<Edge*> edgeList;

// init your vertex here
Vertex(int label);

// connect this vertex to a specific vertex (adding edge)
void connectTo(int end);

};
#endif /* Vertex_hpp */
```

Yet, when I run my code I get an error saying that `edgeList is not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Could it be that "Edge.hpp" `#include`s "Vertex.hpp"?

Comment: That's not it. All `Edge.hpp` includes is `<stdio.h>`

Comment: You're trying to use member variable of `Vertex` in member function of `Graph`? What's the relationship between them?

Comment: `Graph.hpp` includes `Vertex.hpp` and `Vertex.hpp` include `Edge.hpp`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Graph::displayGraph()`, you are iterating on a list of `Vertex`s. To access the edgeList field from an object, you need to reference it as such. See the following code:

```
void Graph::displayGraph(){
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices[vertices.size()-1].label; i++){
        cout << vertices[i].label << ": ";
        for(int j = 0; j <= vertices[i].edgeList.size(); j++){
            if(vertices[i].edgeList[j].start==i){
                cout << vertices[i].edgeList[j].end;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TriskalJM, thank you for edit. Now it is much better